# Postgres Problems with Phusion Deployment (Rails)

Tags: postgresql

```
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "test-postgres"
```

So I have a postgres server hosting a side of my database access for my Rails application and I have a database for production set up and a user for production set up but I keep getting the previous error whenever I try to view my Rails application from a browser. Can somebody help me out? I have the postgres user created and the database created already...

Comment: Did you do a Google search for the error message? Also: PostgreSQL version, how you set PostgreSQL up, server OS and version, etc etc.

Comment: 8.4 postgres version, ubuntu 10.04 for server version, yes but every time i google for the answer to this question i just get the same answer which is create the user and create the database to have it initialize. the database and the user are created though so i dont know what to do. i just used aptitude to install postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Ubuntu documentation on their PostgreSQL packages, which you'll find in /usr/share/doc . Alternately, there's a nice wiki page on it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL (first hit for "ubuntu postgresql").

You have a `pg_hba.conf` file that's set to try to use `ident` authentication for `host` (TCP/IP) connections, but you don't have an `identd` running or you're trying to connect as a different PostgreSQL user to your unix username.

You need to set a paassword for the user and change the authentication method to `md5`. See the [client authentication chapter of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).

(A truly definitive answer would be easier to make if you'd given the command you ran to get that error).

Comment: i just was trying to view my rails application from the web and that's when i get that error, wasn't any command i was using specifically. i have set the ident authentication method to trust on every local connection but it still throws that error. is there anything else i should be doing?

Comment: I also can't connect with "psql -d myDb -U username -W"

Comment: The following however does work: "psql -U test-postgres -h localhost -d test-postgres_production"

Comment: i'm dumb! fixed it! you were right

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly overcome this by changing the `local` line in `pga_hba.conf`

If you change the column `ident` to `trust`, it will make this problem go away.

I'm sure some people would have a security concern, but from my perspective, if someone has already got access to your server, a password for the database isn't gonna be much help.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html I know this isn't the same version of Postgres, but the concept hasn't really changed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: <code>
local   all             postgres                               trust
local   all             test-postgres                               trust

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                              trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32         trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5 </code>

Comment: that is what i changed my pga_hba.conf file to but i still get the same error...